# why github api return null for language field for repositories

Tags: github, github-api

Below is an example which returns null in Language field, but not sure why it returns null?

```
https://api.github.com/repos/wycats/merb-more
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because there is no code related content recognized in the repository. Github automatically updates the language field after every push event. For a language to be recognized it should be listed in the [Linguist library](https://github.com/github/linguist). Ref. [About repository languages](https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-languages/)

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT the `language` field signifies the most-used programming language in the repo. If no languages are detected that would be null.

You can check the list of languages with

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/languages
```

If it's empty, you'll see `null` in the general repo info. If it's got some entries, you should see the most-used one instead - for example try these URLs:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/testoob/testoob/languages
https://api.github.com/repos/testoob/testoob
```